# How do I ensure all Wordpress headers have a transparent background?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Now that I have my repeating background within the **#main-content** portion of *styles.css*, I want to ensure that all headings (with the exception of a few 'button-like-elements') have a transparent background. The problem is that I can't exactly figure out where I'd do that.

To illustrate my issue, I will focus on two pages:

1. **[Homepage](http://longgame.org/)** : The titles "Core Subjects" and "Recent Posts" both have a *white* background.
2. **[Blog Post](http://longgame.org/2012/02/95-hours-in-the-wasteland/)** : Everything looks fine until you get to the comments. "3 Comments" and "Leave a Reply" have the same problem.

Please let me know if I have omitted some necessary data, and thank in advance to you scripting-angel(s).

Comment: Oh, and I forgot! Here is my styles.css file: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/y3p94iqh5h3winl/HUFeIEGLVi

Comment: It's visible through your website already: http://longgame.org/wp-content/themes/Pytheas/style.css?ver=3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

See line 99 ish where the background property is set for `.heading span`. You'll want something like...

```
.heading span {
    background: none;
}
```

btw, are you familiar with how to use the Inspect Element feature in your browser? It'll make your life easier for finding out these things. In a modern browser, like Chromium or Firefox, right-click any part of your page and select 'Inspect Element' to see what's going on.

Comment: Actually, I _have_ been using inspect element. It just shows how green I am. Thanks _very much_ for schooling me. :)

EDIT: Actually, that hasn't removed the background. I've dumped caches and what not. I will inspect away.

Comment: I'm beginning to get the hang of that Chrome console. I basically selected the element within the console and then changed the background property via the tool. GUI: The only way I _get_ anything. :)